# Making a JavaScript Discord bot have a "Do not disturb" status

Tags: discord.js

I am making a simple JavaScript Discord bot and I was wondering if it was still possible for my bot to have a "do not disturb status so people know not to dm it back.

```
bot.once("ready", () => {
  console.log(chalk`{blue CODED BY MAPLER © 2021 :)}`)
  console.log(chalk`{green ✔} Ready to give results!`);
  bot.user.setActivity(config.status.message, { type: playying});
});
```

Comment: That should be it https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence

Comment: Thank you, but how do I have a playing status at the same time as idle?

Comment: #setPresence takes an object containing activities and a status. The status is your idle and the activity can be the game it "plays".

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
client.user.setStatus('dnd')
```

In your `client.on("ready")` place.

This may not be exactly correct because I am doing this off the top of my head, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js v12

```js
client.user.setPresence(
    { 
        activity: { 
            name: '?help', 
            type: 'LISTENING' 
        }, 
        status: "idle" // online, idle, invisible, dnd
    }
)
```

Discord.js v13

```js
client.user.setPresence(
    { 
        activities: [
            { 
                name: "?help" , 
                type: 'LISTENING' 
            }
        ], 
        status: "idle" // online, idle, invisible, dnd
    }
)
```